# Comparison between point. and int

Tags: c

When I type hk on the Output, it did not say HONG KONG, It just say INPUT ERROR everytime.

```
char dc,ds[15];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
p("Destination Code: ");
s("%s", &dc);

if(dc=="hk"){
    strcpy(ds, "HONG KONG");
}
else{
    strcpy(ds, "INPUT ERROR");
}

p("Destination: %s", ds);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here.

1. You have declared `dc` as `char` type and trying to read in the `string` type.
2. You cannot use `==`  to compare two `strings`, you should use `strcmp` instead.

**Example:**

```
  char dc[3];    
  scanf("%2s", dc);
  if(strcmp(dc,"hk") == 0){
    strcpy(ds, "HONG KONG");
  }
  else{
     strcpy(ds, "INPUT ERROR");
  }
```

Comment: So. What am I going to change??

Comment: @Kokie You should declare `dc` as `char` array and use `strcmp` to compare the `string` instead of `==`. Refer the example section in the answer.

Comment: THANK YOU VERYY MUCHH Kirann :D